# Tailwind Carousel Component auto-scroll not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am new to css and I am trying to use tailwind Carousel (from tw-elements) with my gatsby react app and everything is working fine except for the auto-scroll on page load. I copied the first example from this [link](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/#basic), which already has auto-scroll enabled.

On playing with it a bit longer I realised that the auto-scroll starts working once I interact with the carousel - only via the next/prev buttons. If I click on the indicators before clicking on the next/prev buttons the autoplay never starts.

I tried some workarounds that are probably not ideal but didn't work anyway -

1. I tried manually clicking the next button on pageload with the help of `ref.current.click` but it still does not start the auto-scroll. I need to hover my mouse over the Carousel and then exit for the auto-scroll to begin.
2. I also tried setting `data-bs-pause={false}` to not make it stop on mouse hover but that just stops the auto-scroll completely.

Is this due to some differences between how gatsby and tw-elements work or am I missing something basic here?

ps - the attributes I passed for the the carousel were picked from the [bootstrap documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/#docsTabsAPI), since tw-elements are built on top of bootstrap.